# Syntax error js object to json

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

Hello i'm using Backbone here i have an issue, my 'history' attribute will be

```
history = history + ' * ' + 'Attribute "used" modified from ' + !this.changed.used + ' to ' + this.changed.used + ' by ' + LOGGED_USER.get("fisrtName") + " " + LOGGED_USER.get("name") + ' the ' + (new Date());
```

But when i do

```
this.set("history", history);
var json = JSON.stringify(this.toJSON())
```

the json returned is kind of corrupted with \

Any idea ?

Comment: Please post the JSON (or a sample)

Comment: What does `kind of corrupted` mean? Please provide a proper problem description

Comment: returns : "history":" * Attribute \"used\" modified from false to true by Jon Doe the Fri Nov 20 2015 14:35:55 GMT+0100 (Paris, Madrid)"

After getting the request of the ajax it returns me error 500 but if i set "history":"No history" it works

Comment: That is what JSON looks like. How else is JSON supposed to tell whether a `"` in the middle of a value is a `"`, or the end of the string?

Comment: Please don't edit "solved" or otherwise place the answer in your question. If you have an answer, post it as an answer below.

Comment: Solved : I had a php function that was replacing "\" by "" causing troubles in php/sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `"` needs to be escaped in strings, it is not *corrupted*.

```
{ "key" : "I am \"valid\"" }
```